# Hot to format time as '00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs'?

Tags: php

I want to format a time retrieved from the database (01:00:00) as so:

```
01 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs
```

But the following attempt has not worked and is giving me errors so my question is how can I get the format I want for the time above:

```
<strong>Start Date:</strong> <?php echo date("H"),"Hrs",date("i"),"Mins",date("s"),"Secs",strtotime($detailsSessionDuration)); ?>
```

Error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: The `date()` function needs a second argument, the time you want to format. Otherwise it uses the current time, not the time from the DB.

Comment: @JohnConde updated error above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<strong>Start Date:</strong> 
<?php 

    $time = strtotime($detailsSessionDuration);
    echo date("H", $time),"Hrs",date("i", $time),"Mins",date("s", $time),"Secs"; 
?>
```

Comment: You should mark the answer that worked for you as accepted. Keep in mind that what @Glavic suggested is better.

Answer (score 5):

Try with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)::[createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) :

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '12:34:56');
echo $d->format('H \H\r\s i \M\i\n\s s \S\e\c\s');
```

or you can use just [DateTime::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) which supports `24 hour notation` [time format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) :

```
$d = new DateTime('12:34:56');
echo $d->format('H \H\r\s i \M\i\n\s s \S\e\c\s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = explode(':', $detailsSessionDuration);
printf("%s Hrs %s Mins %s Secs", $arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]);
```